# CSS centered title to the side in a li

Tags: css, html-lists, word-wrap

My issue is pretty hard to describe with words so I took a picture of what I am after:

http://p.twimg.com/Aq4o04vCMAEdhdD.jpg

I can't get the `.title` to sit on a line by itself, with the description happily wrapping.

Here is a fiddle of the structure I am working with - http://jsfiddle.net/rEpgB/2/

Any pointers would be appreciated :)

*Sidenote*

I used http://hipsteripsum.me/ for my dummy text if you were wondering...

Comment: Please rotate that pic! My neck hurts!

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I was going to post an answer, then the post was flooded by valid answers. I'd go with John Conde's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then use this http://jsfiddle.net/rEpgB/25/

```
<ul>
    <li class="container">
        <div class="title" style="">Title Is Here</div>
        <div class="description" style="">Cred vice synth cliche, salvia banksy chambray organic blog. Quinoa organic fap 8-bit, fingerstache butcher gastropub vinyl.<div>
    </li>

    <li class="container">
        <div class="title" style="">Another title</div>
        <div class="description " style="">Authentic 8-bit messenger bag PBR master cleanse, organic fanny pack beard raw denim etsy.<div>
            </li>
</ul>
​
li.container {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width:90%
}

.title {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.description {
    color: #888;
    display: table-cell;
}

.float-left {
float: left;
}​
```

Comment: Hmm I take that back, I overlooked the inline styling. Ideally there would be no need to define any widths, percentage or otherwise, as the width should be inherited from the title width.

Comment: I want my points back!  JK, if you use display: table-cell it replicates a tables behaviour, as you can see in my updated fiddle.

Comment: Nice you can have all your points back for `display: table-cell;` I have dropped the width rule in http://jsfiddle.net/dFZLF/1/ which works nicely as intended

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use you an `<hx>` tag since that's what they're there for? It solves your problem and is semantically correct:

```
<ul>
    <li class="container">
        <h2>Title Is Here</h2>
        <span class="description">Cred vice synth cliche, salvia banksy chambray organic blog. Quinoa organic fap 8-bit, fingerstache butcher gastropub vinyl.<span>
    </li>

    <li class="container">
        <h2>Another title</h2>
        <span class="description">Authentic 8-bit messenger bag PBR master cleanse, organic fanny pack beard raw denim etsy.<span>
            </li>
</ul>


li.container {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

span.description {
    color: #888;
}​
​
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as header tags default to having the title on a single line by itself. This isn't what I want, though I agree it is semantically an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7eLH/)

All I did was add a new float element in the `span.title`:

```
li.container {
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
}

span.title {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    float: left; // added this float
}

span.description {
    color: #888;
}​
```

Comment: For more control, you should probably use the `ul` as your "container" rather than an individual `li`.  It will give you more control over your styling.  Just nest `ul`'s if you need multiple containers like in your example

Comment: And updated it John... Normally I do.  Was in a rush to post, boss came sneaking up behind me. :)

Comment: This does work for that fiddle, but if you extend the length of the `.description`, it wraps under the `.title`

Comment: It does.  If you make better containers, rather than using `li` elements, you will have more control.  I would suggest using `div` to seperate the information rather than `li`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are having to use span as the a wrapper. You can just use an `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc. tag and it will break for you.

Change

```
<span class="title">title</span>`
```

to

```
<h1 class="title"></h1>`
```

then change your css to

```
h1.title {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rEpgB/17/

Don't use "width" with padding right or left, it's a rule.